I want to match 6 or fewer digits in a string, if there are "/" or "-" between them
It should match:

"abc 12-34 def" precisely "12-34"
"Phone number: 123/45", precisely "123/45"
"sequence: 12//-34", precisely "12//-34"
"My code is 1-2-3-4", precisely "1-2-3-4"

It should not match:

"too many: 1234-567-89"

"too many; 1234-567"


Here is what I have tried:
pattern = r'\d([\/-]\d){1,5}'

but didn't succeed

So you have a digit at start, a digit at end, and in the middle something with up to four digits and at least one [-/]. Doesn't look so simple...

In your pattern, this part \d([\/-]\d expects a match for either / or -
You might use a single digit, and repeat 1 - 5 times a digit with zero or more occurrences of - or / in between.
On the left you can place a negative lookbehind and on the right a negative lookahead to assert not - / or a digit to mark the boundaries.
(?<![/\d-])\d(?:[/-]*\d){1,5}(?![/\d-])

See a regex demo

This fails to -123, but not sure what's the desired output for inputs like this.

@HaoWu The title states or "-" between them where "them" being a digit, and the OP did not try to match an optional leading hyphen.
